# Is using wildcards for hostnames in dhcp module of dnsmasq possible?

Tags: dhcp, hostname, dhcp-server, dnsmasq

I want to have all machines with a hostname that starts with `foobar-` assigned an IP from a specific range with an infinite lease. All other machines should have a volatile IP. I did the following but the configuration file was not valid...

```
dhcp-host=set:baz,foobar-*
dhcp-range=tag:baz,192.168.1.1,192.168.1.42,infinite
dhcp-range=192.168.1.43,192.168.1.254,12h
```

Obviously it is possible to use wildcards with MAC addresses, but is there a way to do it by the given hostname?

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding meaning of the respective `dhcp-host` field. `hostname` is the name that will be assigned to the machine at hand, not something that dnsmasq obtains from it.